# Pickerview : how to combine 2 separate code into 1 place?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

how to put this code below?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *year = [dateYear objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *month = [dateMonth objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    NSString *day = [dateDay objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:2]];
    labelDate1.text = [year stringByAppendingFormat:@" : %@ : %@", month, day];
}
```

into here?

```
- (IBAction)setDateBtn1:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    viewPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

My problem is, i have two button setDateBtn1 for labelDate1 and setDateBtn2 for labelDate2, both button calls one pickerView for input data that show at each label. After selecting date, it appears in labelDate1 only, no matter what button i call my pickerview, but what i want is setDateBtn1 for labelDate1 and setDateBtn2 for labelDate2. I hope you understand my english. For any help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have one picker method but two buttons (or labels) where either of which can bring up your picker.  Selecting something in the picker should set label1 or label2.

So... here's an opportunity for you to make use of the picker view's "`tag`" property.

When bringing up the picker, set the "`viewPicker.tag`" to "`1`" (for label 1) and "`2`" if the button for label 2 brings up the picker.

Then, in your "`didSelectRow`" function, you'll know which label you're doing the picking for.  And you can do something like this:

```
if(pickerView.tag == 1)
    labelDate1.text = [year stringByAppendingFormat:@" : %@ : %@", month, day];
else
    labelDate2.text = [year stringByAppendingFormat:@" : %@ : %@", month, day];
```

Hopefully I explained this well enough for you to keep going.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a property to hold the "active" label. When button 1 is pressed, set this property to label 1. When button 2 is pressed, set it to label 2.

Then, in your picker view delegate method shown above, update the active label instead of always updating label 1 as you are doing at the moment.